# QPushButton with a custom shape

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton

I want to make some buttons look like buttons you see in Skype. How to style a `QPushButton` with a custom shape? I don't have any idea for doing this. So I need some suggestions. For example, I want my `QPushButton` to look like this [image](http://meship.com/Blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/virtual-call-center.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `QT-Stylesheets` to style a `QPushButton` whatever the way you like it to be. You can style the `border-image` property of the `QPushButton`, there is an example [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/stylesheet-examples.html#qpushbutton-and-images)  explains just that. Go through [documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/stylesheet.html). Specially study [css box-modal](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/stylesheet-customizing.html).

But your requirement can be fulfilled simply by setting following style sheet to your `QPushButton`. You have to prepare PNG images using an image editing software like GIMP, so the image will have a transparent background.

```
QPushButton#myPushButton
{
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url(":/transparent_image.png");
    background-repeat: none;    
    border: none;
}
```

Furthermore, you might want to style `:hover` and `:pressed` pseudo states as well by setting two additional images, so it will look more like a button in terms of its behavior.

```
QPushButton#myPushButton:hover
{
   background-image: url(":/transparent_image_hover.png");
}

QPushButton#myPushButton:pressed
{
   background-image: url(":/transparent_image_pressed.png");
}
```

I have virtually spoon-fed the answer for you, so keep in mind that it is necessary to be specific when looking for an answer. So people can help you with more focused answers.

Comment: I know this method but if your button have to be in any form (shape) how to do that?? suppose that you have one picture the same in this link: http://meship.com/Blog/2011/07/14/move-to-cloud-computing-drives-virtual-call-center-trend/  (world+headphones) how could you make a push button with exactly the same shape??

Comment: Your question was more generic hence you were presented with a generic answer. If you can post your style-sheet for the QPushButton of yours, I can be more helpful with a specific answer. All I can say is, your requirement can be achieved at style-sheet level

Comment: I have edited my answer to suit your specific need; styling a QPushButton to look it like an image shown in this link http://meship.com/Blog/2011/07/14/move-to-cloud-computing-drives-virtual-call-center-trend/